# Trying to use select of @ngrx/store causes undefined variable

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ngrx

I have been following https://github.com/ngrx/example-app very closely while creating a project in Angular.

I'm trying to select a value from a root reducer in my component, and it is not working.

The component (and line) in question:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as rootReducer from '../../reducer/';
import * as layoutActions from '../../actions/layout';
 

 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  template: `
        <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          linkme
        </div>
          <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
          <a routerLink="/groups">Groups</a>
          <div class="button"  (click)="toggleAddModal()">add thing</div>
        </nav>
        <add-link-modal [open]="showAddModal$ | async"></add-link-modal>
        `,
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.scss']

})

export class NavBarComponent {

  showAddModal$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store : Store<rootReducer.State>) {
   ****** this.showAddModal$ = store.select(rootReducer.getShowAddModal); ****** this is the line that is breaking
  }

  toggleAddModal()
  {
    this.store.dispatch({type: layoutActions.TOGGLE_ADD_MODAL})
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
...
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from './reducer/'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
...


@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.provideStore(reducers)
    ...
  ],
  ..
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**reducers/index.ts**

```js
import { combineReducers } from '@ngrx/store';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromLinks from './links';
import * as fromLayout from './layout';

export interface State{
    layout: fromLayout.LayoutState
    links: fromLinks.LinkState
}

const globalReducers = {
    layoutReducer:fromLayout.layoutReducer,
    linksReducer: fromLinks.linkReducer
};

const globalState: ActionReducer<State> = combineReducers(globalReducers);

export function reducers(state: any, action: any) { return globalState(state, action);}

/*layout*/
export const getLayoutState = (state: State) => state.layout;
export const getShowAddModal = createSelector(getLayoutState, fromLayout.getShowAddModal);
```

**reducers/layout.ts**

```js
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as layoutActions from '../actions/layout';

export interface LayoutState {
    showAddModal: boolean;
}

const initialState: LayoutState = {
    showAddModal: false,
};
 
export function layoutReducer(state = initialState, action: Action): LayoutState {

    switch (action.type) {
        case layoutActions.TOGGLE_ADD_MODAL:
            const newBoolState = state.showAddModal ? false : true ;
            return { 
                showAddModal: newBoolState
            };
 
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const getShowAddModal = (state: LayoutState) => state.showAddModal; *** This is the undefined value
```

I am getting a TypeError: `Cannot read property 'showAddModal' of undefined`, in the method `getShowAddModal` in layout.ts. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? It is almost exact as in the example. Here is the reducer folder containing the files I have been closely following: https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/tree/master/src/app/reducers

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Store devtools? If you are, can you see the value of the `showAddModal` property?

Comment: @notANerdDev Yes, it is showing the correct state. `layoutReducer.showAddModal` is indeed false.

Comment: Can you try changing the names inside the global reducers. From `layoutReducer` to `layout`. Basically keep the attribute names the same for the State interface and the Reducers.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you! This will help me avoid similar errors.